# PyQt 5 CheckBox State Efficient wAy

Tags: python, pyqt

Firstly, have a good day to all,
I've been trying to learn PyQt5 nowadays. I wrote a code about check box state changing depends on other check box. It looks work. I wonder your feed back.
Thank you for your time.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class CheckBox(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CheckBox, self).__init__()
        self.features()
        self.checkbox()

    def features(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Check Box")
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 200, 200)

        self.show()

    def checkbox(self):
        # Check Box
        self.check_box1 = QCheckBox("Alive")
        self.check_box2 = QCheckBox("Dead")
        self.check_box3 = QCheckBox("No Idea")
        # Check Box State
        self.check_box3.setChecked(True)
        self.check_box1.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
        self.check_box2.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
        self.check_box2.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
        # Button
        self.push_button1 = QPushButton("Send")
        self.push_button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sendmessage(self.check_box1.isChecked(),
                                                                self.check_box2.isChecked(),
                                                           self.check_box3.isChecked(), self.label1))
        # Label
        self.label1 = QLabel("")
        # Vertical Lay Out
        v_box1 = QVBoxLayout()
        v_box1.addWidget(self.check_box1)
        v_box1.addWidget(self.check_box2)
        v_box1.addWidget(self.check_box3)
        v_box1.addWidget(self.push_button1)
        v_box1.addWidget(self.label1)
        # Horizontal Lay Out
        h_box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        h_box1.addStretch()
        h_box1.addLayout(v_box1)
        h_box1.addStretch()
        # Set Lay Out
        self.setLayout(h_box1)

    def onStateChange(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            if self.sender() == self.check_box1:
                self.check_box2.setChecked(False)
                self.check_box3.setChecked(False)
            elif self.sender() == self.check_box2:
                self.check_box1.setChecked(False)
                self.check_box3.setChecked(False)
            elif self.sender() == self.check_box3:
                self.check_box1.setChecked(False)
                self.check_box2.setChecked(False)

    def sendmessage(self, cbox1, cbox2, cbox3, lab):
        if cbox1:
            lab.setText("Check Box 1")
        elif cbox2:
            lab.setText("Check Box 2")
        elif cbox3:
            lab.setText("Check Box 3")
        else:
            lab.setText("No Selection")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
checkbox = CheckBox()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a mistake, this line is defined twice (line 28):

```
self.check_box2.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
```

Therefore the event `onStateChange` is triggered twice when you check `check_box2`, which is logical.

I think you did a copy paste and the last should be `check_box3`. But your **naming conventions** are not intuitive, give your objects some more **meaningful names**, otherwise how are you going to tell the difference from your code.

If what you want is **mutually exclusive** checkboxes the implementation could be more straightforward. Personally I prefer to use radio buttons like in plain HTML because this is more intuitive (it is immediately obvious that only one answer is allowed).

First approach: a generic method that loops on the checkboxes in your form and unchecks all of them except the sender. Then you can simplify code and get rid of `if/elif`

Second approach: use QT built-in features. You could wrap your checkboxes in a `QButtonGroup` container.

> A rectangular box before the text label appears when a QCheckBox
>   object is added to the parent window. Just as QRadioButton, it is also
>   a selectable button. Its common use is in a scenario when the user is
>   asked to choose one or more of the available options.
>
> Unlike Radio buttons, check boxes are not mutually exclusive by
>   default. In order to restrict the choice to one of the available
>   items, the check boxes must be added to QButtonGroup.

and:

> **As mentioned earlier, checkBox buttons can be made mutually exclusive
>   by adding them in the `QButtonGroup` object.**
>
> ```
> self.bg = QButtonGroup()
> self.bg.addButton(self.b1,1)
> self.bg.addButton(self.b2,2)
> ```
>
> `QButtonGroup` object, provides abstract container for buttons and
>   doesn’t have a visual representation. It emits `buttonCliked()` signal
>   and sends Button object’s reference to the slot function `btngroup()`.

Source: [PyQt - QCheckBox Widget](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qcheckbox_widget.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It mean a lot for me. I will definetly not ignore your feedback